# Symfony3 - Form Event Subscriber not working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form called `ProfileType`, when i submit this form I want to process something so a form event subscriber i thought should do the job so I went and implemented that but when i submit the form the events are not getting fired and I am seeing the events in profiler under tab "Not called events"

So this is what I did, I am not sure what I am missing here.
This is my `ProfileType` class and as you will notice i have `->addEventSubscriber(new SkillsListener())`

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\EventListener\SkillsListener;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('street')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('state')
            ->addEventSubscriber(new SkillsListener())
        ;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => 'profile'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_user';
    }


}
```

I then created my listner

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class SkillsListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT      => 'onPreSubmit',
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA    => 'onPreSetData',
        );
    }


    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {

        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        dump($user, $form);
        die;

    }

    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        dump($user, $form);
        die;
    }
}
```

I did `dump()` and `die` just to debug what i get so i can implement the process i need but the event does not fire.

I thought may be I need to add something in `services.yml` but that does not help either

```
app.form_event_listener.skills_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\SkillsListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

I do not get any error, its just that the event does not fire. What am i missing here? Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**
This is the controller linked with form

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/edit", name="internee_profile_edit")
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editProfileAction( Request $request ) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    /** @var User $user */
    $user             = $this->getUser();
    $profileForm      = $this->createForm( ProfileType::class, $user );
    $profileForm->handleRequest( $request );
    if ( $profileForm->isValid() ) {
        $em->persist( $user );
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash( 'success', $this->get( 'translator' )->trans( 'user.profile.success.saved' ) );
    }
    return $this->render( 'AppBundle:jobseeker:profile-edit.html.twig', array( 'form' => $profileForm->createView() ) );
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have updated my `ProfileType` to use a listener and that is not working either.

```
public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
    $builder
        ->add( 'name' )
        ->add( 'street' )
        ->add( 'city' )
        ->add( 'state' )
    ;
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        array( $this, 'onPreSetData' )
    );

}

public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    dump($event);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you instantiate the form and process it?

Comment: Can you try adding a listener and seeing if that is fired? `$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) { dump($event); exit; });`

Comment: Take out the services stuff.  Form events are handled differently.  What you posted really looks like it should work.  Make sure you are editing the files you think you are.  Maybe verify the route is actually getting to the expected controller action.  Verify the form is actually being posted?  Maybe the validation is failing?  Gonna be something strange.

Comment: @Cerad i feel like slapping my self, yes i was looking at the wrong action.